# mapbox GL not able to have more than 5 markers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to incorporate markers on a map using Mapbox GL on my rails app.

In my controller file i have:

```
@boatramps = Boatramp.all.limit(6)
@geojson = {"type" => "FeatureCollection", "features" => []}
@boatramps.each do |boatramp|
  @geojson["features"] << {
    geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [boatramp.long, boatramp.lat]
    },
    properties: {
    title: boatramp.id,
    :'marker-symbol' => 'monument'
    }
  }
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json{render json: @geojson}
end
```

for my ajax call I have

```
style.layers.push({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "layout": {
      "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-12",
      "text-field": "{title}",
      "text-font": "Open Sans Semibold, Arial Unicode MS Bold",
      "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
      "text-anchor": "top"
    },
    "paint": {
      "text-size": 12
    }
  });
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/virginia',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        var markers = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({ data: response});

        map.addSource('markers', markers);
    },
    error: function(){

    }
})
```

When I have 5 markers the call works fine and i get the boatramp id to show.(Also having issues with the "icon image" to show) As soon as I increase the limit to 6 or more. I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'leaf' of undefined`

As I zoom in and out on the map it executes the same error. Additionally, once I Have a considerable amount of objects 40 +, some of them don't show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/987

I also asked aboutit on Github yesterday and I was told it would be fixed in the next release, in about a week.